# Add space between number and letters in a string dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want space between the numbers and letters in a string.
example:
String = "KL11AB2432";
to
String = "KL 11 AB 2432";

Comment: you can loop and use `ascii-code`  to detect the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y'all are working too hard.  Reach for a regex!

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  const data = "KL11AB2432";
  print(insertSpaces(data));
}

String insertSpaces(String input) {
  final reg = RegExp(r"([A-Z]+|\d+)");
  final pieces = reg.allMatches(input);
  return pieces.map((e) => e.group(0)).join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String str = "KL11AB2432";
  List<Object> newList = [];

  List<String> strList = str.split("").toList();

  for (var i = 0; i < strList.length; i++) {
    if (int.tryParse(strList[i]) != null) {
      if ((i - 1) >= 0 && int.tryParse(strList[i - 1]) == null) {
        newList.add(" ");
        newList.add(strList[i]);
      } else {
        newList.add(strList[i]);
      }
    } else {
      if ((i - 1) >= 0 && int.tryParse(strList[i - 1]) != null) {
        newList.add(" ");
        newList.add(strList[i]);
      } else {
        newList.add(strList[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  print(newList);
  print(newList.join().toString());
```

and Result =>

> [K, L,  , 1, 1,  , A, B,  , 2, 4, 3, 2]

> KL 11 AB 2432

Answer (score 0):

I am using try catch to check the int type,

```dart
bool isInt(String data) {
    try {
      int.parse(data);
      return true;
    } catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }

void main() {
  String data = "KL11AB2432";
  bool isPrevIsNum = false;
  bool isPrevIsChar = false;
  String result = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    bool isIntData = isInt(data[i]);

    if (isIntData) {
      isPrevIsChar = false;
      if (isPrevIsNum) {
        result = "$result${data[i]}";
      } else {
        result = "$result ${data[i]}";
        isPrevIsNum = true;
      }
    } else {
      isPrevIsNum = false;

      if (isPrevIsChar) {
        result = "$result${data[i]}";
      } else {
        result = "$result ${data[i]}";
      }
      isPrevIsChar = true;
    }
  }

  print(result.trim()); // KL 11 AB 2432
}
```

Condition can be merged on upper level I think, but to make it clear I've kept like this. There might be others short way .

Comment: Heey I was already checking this with tryParse.

Are you stealing my answer? :)

Comment: I've no intention on stealing someone answer, I was engaged multiple question, this might be delay, also I saved the question because I was curious about it.

Comment: I'm not serious man.
I was joking

Answer (score 0):

this is an minimal code efficient **O(n)** solution that I tested it :

```
    expect(trimNumString("KL11AB2432"), "KL 11 AB 2432"); // true
```

and here it is :

```
String trimNumString(String text, {String separator = " "}) {
  String result = "";
  List<String> textAsList = text.split("");

  for (int index = 0; index < testAsList.length; index += 1) {
    bool hasReachedTheEdOfList = (index + 1) >= testAsList.length;
    bool hasNotReachedTheEdOfList = !hasReachedTheEdOfList;

    int? currentElement = int.tryParse(testAsList[index]);
    int? nextElement;
    if (hasNotReachedTheEdOfList) {
      nextElement = int.tryParse(testAsList[index + 1]);
    } else {
      separator = "";
    }

    if ((currentElement == null && nextElement is int) ||
        (currentElement is int && nextElement == null)) {
      result += testAsList[index] + separator;

      continue;
    }
    result += testAsList[index];
  }

  return result;
}
```

you can change the separator you want from the method call like this

```
enter code here

trimNumString("KL11AB2432", separator: " ");
```